# Using projection without the annotation @Projection

Tags: java, spring, annotations, projection

### Situation

I inherited some code from a developer that seems to have used undocumented features of spring.

Specifically, it is related to using `@projection` functionality without actually annotating the `interface`as such.

A specific example is the following:

```
public interface DirType extends KeyValInterface  {
    @Value("#{target.id}") String getId();
    @Value("#{target.code}") String getText();
}
```

This should not work according to the official documentation, but it does.

```
public interface DirTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<ABDirType, Long> {
    List<DirType> findAllSummarizedBy(); 
}
```

So the method `findAllSummarizedBy()` of the respository is actually sending a list of `DirType`.

And it is using the `@Value`annotations to do the mapping, but without a `@Projection` annotation.

The `Entity` class is the following:

```
@Data @Entity @Table(name="dir_type") @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class ABDirType {

        private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
        private String code;
    }
```

### Question

Does anyone have any more information about this undocumented feature related to `Projections` and not annotating the interface as a `@Projection` ?

Is this possible in all versions or is it a hidden hack that is risky to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring Data JPA (which you seem to be using here), you can simply use an interface with appropriate getters as projection targets.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) about this (esp. "Example 62. Simple Projection").

There does not seem to be a `@Projection` annotation anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: I see... I just saw the example: Example 63. Renaming a property